# How do I get a list of axes for a figure in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Regarding [`matplotlib.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html), the documentation says there is a class `matplotlib.figure.AxesStack` and that

> The AxesStack is a callable, where ax_stack() returns the current axes

However, when I call `fig.ax_stack()`, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'ax_stack'
```

Comment: @behzad.nouri Thanks. It seems that `get_axes()` returns two object, AxesSubplot, and Axes. But how can I get an AxesStack object for my figure? (So if I add more axes to my figure, then I can get a list of them)

Comment: Becareful about capitalization,`AxesStack` is a class in the module `figure`, the ref `fig` points to a `Figure` object.

Comment: you already have the axes. It is the object ax in the line: fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The property [`.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.axes) returns a list of the [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) objects in the [`Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html) object:

```
ax_list = fig.axes
```

Comment: Thanks! So both `AxesStack` and `Figure` are classes in module `figure`. But the returned `fig` object from `pyplot` does not use any `AxesStack` object to represents its axes? Or maybe the reference to `AxesStack` is just hidden somewhere internally in the `fig` object?

Comment: `fig` is a `Figure` object.  I am not sure where `AxesStack` gets used, but you should probably not be using it.

Comment: If the group of axes is 2D such as if one used `fig,ax=plt.subplots(5,4)`, fig.axes returns a 1D list. How can I get axes objects returned in a 2D array?

Comment: Hold on to the array that comes back from `plt.subplots`.  `fig.axes` has no semantics about the axes layout (which may not map nicely to a grid, ex http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-using-subplotspec ).

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that `fig.axes` is described in that documentation.

Comment: @Joel It's described [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.axes) under the linked page.

Comment: It's deprecated. Please update your answer.

Comment: @burglarhobbit I do not remember us deprecating `fig.axes`, could you point me to documentation or the PR/Issue where that happened?

Comment: @tacaswell I confused `fig.axes` with `AxesStack` in the `matplotlib.figure` class. I was trying to remove x, y axes before saving a 2d array as an image (png) and being unsuccessful at that. So I switched to 'opencv' which was faster. I believe I was trying to force `plt` to save my image without additional components but learned soon enough my approach wasn't too practical.

Comment: @EL_DON have you found how to retrieve axes layout from fig in 2D array form? All I can find from Figure objects is a list of Axes that gives me no info about the actual layout.