# use ply.ylim in matplotlib to set y-axis limit only works for the last subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I'm trying to set y-axis limit for a certain subplot using `plt.ylim`. (in my example, the plot on `ax1`)

However, no matter where I put the command `plt.ylim((10,20))`, it only works on the last subplot (in the following example, it is the plot on `ax2`).

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
x=range(1,100)
y=range(1,100)
plt.ylim((10,20))
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)
```

Only `ax2` will be limited and `ax1` will still be in the original range.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
x=range(1,100)
y=range(1,100)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim((10,20))
```

[screenshot for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBsUK.png)

Running the two blocks of code will produce the same result. I know I can also use other methods like `plt.setp(ax1, ylim=[10,20])`. But I'd like to know how to use `plt.ylim` properly.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: call `set_ylim()` for each ax

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but actually I created a toy example for the problem. I'm running `decomposition_results.plot().suptitle('Multiplicative Decomposition')` and the decomposition result is composed of four elements. Using `.plot()` will directly plot four subplots at once but it is difficult to customize for a certain subplot. So I cannot `set_ylim()` for a certain ax as I didn't create axes.

Comment: Can't you retrieve existing axes with `plt.subplot`? As [per docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) "Add an Axes to the current figure or *retrieve an existing Axes*."

Comment: thx! I retrieved axes objects using `fig.axes` from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104990/how-to-get-a-list-of-axes-for-a-figure-in-pyplot)