# How to edit size of axes text size on SHAP depedence plot in Python

Tags: python, plot, text, shap

I have used this code:
for i in range(len(col_list)):

```
    shap.dependence_plot(i, shap_values, X.values, feature_names=X.columns, dot_size=10, interaction_index=None, x_jitter=-0.5)
```

to generate the following SHAP dependence plot:

[image]

Does anyone know how to modify the size of the text in the x-axis so that it becomes smaller?
For example, 150000 doesn't overlap with 175000...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SHAP, but my guess is it looks like it returns a matplotlib Figure object. In that case, the following should work

```py
shap_figure = shap.dependence_plot(i, shap_values, X.values, feature_names=X.columns, dot_size=10, interaction_index=None, x_jitter=-0.5)

ax_list = shap_figure .axes # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107230/11148296
ax = ax_list[0]
ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Values', fontsize=14)

shap_figure
```